# Error with Sumproduct but no error with Sumifs when finding value in another column between 2 dates/times

Tags: excel, formulas, sumifs

I am trying to find a value that is in column L of another sheet (This workbook may be closed hence Sumproduct over Sumifs) but for some reason the Sumifs works but Sumproduct returns #N/A?

---

Input values and destination values:

Active Sheet

- B2062 = BW3089657
- G2062 = 43303.2336574074 (22/07/2018  01:18:09)
- H2062 = 43303.5145833333 (22/07/2018  12:21:00)

wb.xlsb

- D = BW3089657
- O = 43300 (19/07/2018)
- P = 43304 (23/07/2018)

---

Formulas and return values.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$D:$D=B2062)*(G2062>='[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$O:$O)*(H2062<='[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$P:$P),('[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$L:$L))
```

Returns = #N/A

```
=SUMIFS('[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$L:$L,'[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$D:$D,B2062,'[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$O:$O,"<="&G2062,'[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$P:$P,">="&H2062)
```

Returns = 29.04%

---

I hope I am not making a silly mistake here but given the sumifs formula works i am guessing its an issue with either sumproduct limitations, formatting or my understanding of this formula.

Comment: The entire sumproduct formula looks really strange, are you multiplying parts of the formula that have logical operators in them ? What are you trying to achieve with that ?

Comment: @ M.Douda I want to sum everything that matches 'BW3089657' in wb.xlsb and where the date falls in between the two dates in the columns in wb.xlsb. I have also used: =SUMPRODUCT(--('[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$D:$D=B2062),--(G2062>='[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$O:$O),--(H2062<='[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$P:$P),('[wb.xlsb]Sheet1'!$L:$L)) The formula works until I add the 3rd criteria, yet with this criteria in sumif it works. I have used this sumproduct format multiple times but not with dates. I have also tried rounding down the earlier date to a whole number and rounding up the later date to a while number and still #N/A.